# Android - Check which radio I'm playing

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

I have 2 activities:

Activity A - Listview/Adapter

Activity B - Radio

In activity A, I choose a radio and B plays that radio (service).

But everytime that I choose another radio on the list, activity B is instanciated another time and the radio stops and plays again.

Situation example:

```
# 1 - I'm playing Radio X, I choose X on the list
# 2 - A new instance is created (service is in onCreate() of Activity B)
# 3 - Radio X playing (play() is in onStart() of service)
# 4 - I go back to the list
# 5 - I want to play Radio Y
# 6 - A new instance is created (service is in onCreate() of Activity B)
# 7 - Radio Y playing (play() is in onStart() of service)
# * In onCreate() of service isn't doing nothing
```

Everything is fine, but what happens if I go back to the list and choose the same radio, for example:

```
# 1 - Radio Y playing
# 2 - I go back to the list
# 3 - I wanna go to Radio Y again
# 4 - A new instance is created (service is in onCreate() of Activity B) (I don't want this)
# 5 - Radio Y stops and plays again (I don't want this)
```

I'd like to have a way to check if the radio is playing is the same radio that I wanna go, and don't create a new instance and don't stop and play the same radio again.

Edit:

ListView

```
if (item == "Radio 1"){
       Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Radio.class);
       intent.putExtra("radio", "http://test1.com");
       this.startActivity(intent);
} else if (item == "Radio 2"){
       Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Radio.class);
       intent.putExtra("radio", "http://test2.com");
       this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Radio.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent music = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service.class);
    music.putExtra("url", this.getIntent().getStringExtra("radio"));
    startService(music);
}
```

Service.java

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Multiplayer m = new MultiPlayer();
    m.playAsync(intent.getExtras().getString("url"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my answer a bit:

You have 2 options (depending on :

Store the playing url in the Service (in onStart) and compare it with the new url being send.

```
private String mCurrentUrl;

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {    
    String newUrl = intent.getExtras().getString("url");

    if ((newUrl.equals(mCurrentUrl)) {
        mCurrentUrl = newUrl;
        Multiplayer m = new MultiPlayer();  
        m.playAsync(mCurrentUrl );
    }
}
```

or:

Define a interface of the Service [(AIDL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) which retrieves the current radio channel. If you let the activity bind to it you can call this method to retrieve the current channel. Note: that you have to start the Service using startService and then bind to it directly. (Else you Service is killed after your Activity is killed)

Comment: Thanks! But I still didn't understand how this code will help me. This code will see if a instance already exists, then I could verify inside this code if the new streaming link is the same streaming link of service and after that, if not, stop the radio and start with the new link, is it?

Comment: I edited my question, I didn't use bind, it was a simple service. In this way like I did, is always creating a new instance of Radio, always enters in onCreate() method of Radio and always enters in onStart() method of Service. I'd like to have a simple way for this :/

Comment: A Service won't be recreated if it is already running. So if you check the current url to the new url in onStart of the Service you can choose to do nothing.

Comment: But how I'll check new url? mCurrentUrl is null when I tried to pick another radio :/ And about the new instance created everytime that I choose a radio on listview, even service is not being created, is it a good practice?